# How to Get the deleted File/Folders using FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

How to get the complete list of deleted files if user delete the a root folder:

Ex: c:\A\B\C\D\F\read.txt

If user delete the root folder A, I need to get the files/folders realted to A, Is there any API in C# for this?

Can we get use the root folder path and retrieve the related files from teh RecycleBin?
I dont't know if user clicks Shift + Delete, how we can get it from RecyleBIn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't an API that will tell you which files have been deleted. You *could* list the contents of the Recycle Bin but it is not guaranteed to be accurate (because of the reason you describe in your question: *Shift+Delete*).

Short of maintaining a list of existing files at any point in time or monitoring disk changes with `FileSystemWatcher` (or possibly an OS filter driver), I think you're out of luck.

I am curious though, why would you want to?

Comment: The actual issue is  FileSystemWatcher has an issue, if I delete a Nested File b(c:\b\c\d), Filewatcher generates only one event for the root B, but if I delete shift + delete, Filewacther genearates events for all sub folder and files,

Comment: @HPFE455 The reason is because `SHIFT + DEL` actually does a file system deletion. When you just use `DEL` it's a file system **move** to the Recycle Bin.

Comment: @Yuck - I didn't test it but that actually make sense. I learned (another) something today :)

Comment: is there any way to do both Del and shift + del in a similar way.. I need to get all events

Comment: @HPFE455 - It isn't the same action so why would you expect them both to be treated the same? They actually mean 2 different things.

Comment: I can maintain a list of subfolders and send each individual folder, send message, but the problem is its very difficult to manage all file names inside  each folder..

Comment: Babcock, we have a requirement, if user delete  a folder, need to maintain the subfolders by another application

Comment: @HPFE455 - If it is too cumbersome to handle the `FileSystemWatcher` events then you may be better off using a polling approach.